# GAE Python, XML - ElementSoap & ElementTree, HTTP server communication (WSDL)

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, soap, elementtree

This task is about generation session id, And this is totally new for me,

Here am using GAE, & my destination url:**http://203.215.51.43/GVSignOn/ExecutePortType?WSDL**, for this implementation i'm
referring these docs [elementsoap](http://effbot.org/zone/elementsoap-1.htm), [soapWebservice-GAE](http://www.bloing.net/2011/01/soap-webservice-gae-python-howto/) & [Element-Soap](http://www.sis.utoronto.ca/web_services/code_samples.html)

& i have written some procedure as well,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from elementsoap.ElementSOAP import *
from elementtree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, QName

NS_SOAP_ENV = "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}"
NS_XSI = "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}"
NS_XSD = "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}"

class SoapService:
    def __init__(self, url=None):
        self.__client = HTTPClient(url or self.url)
    def call(self, action, request):
       # build SOAP envelope
       envelope = Element(NS_SOAP_ENV + "Envelope")
       body = SubElement(envelope, NS_SOAP_ENV + "Body")
       body.append(request)
       # call the server
       response = self.__client.do_request(
          tostring(envelope),
          extra_headers=[("SOAPAction", action)]
       )

       return response.getroot().find(body.tag)[0]

def SoapRequest(method):
    # create a SOAP request element
    request = Element(method)
    request.set(
       NS_SOAP_ENV + "operation",
       "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    )

    return request


def SoapElement(parent, name, type=None, text=None):
   # add a typed SOAP element to a request structure
   elem = SubElement(parent, name)
   if type:
      if not isinstance(type, QName):
          type = QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", type)
      elem.set(NS_XSI + "type", type)
   elem.text = text
   return elem



class GVService(SoapService):
  url = 203.215.51.43:80/GVSignOn/ExecutePortType
  def SignOnReq(self):
    action = 'urn:stc:egate:jce:prjGV_prjGV_BC_Redeem_OTDs:jcdGV_SignOnWSDL:signOn'
    request = SoapRequest('{' + self.url  + '}SignOnReq')
    SoapElement(request, "TerminalId", "string", 'T1081')
    SoapElement(request, "StoreCode", "string", '1006')
    SoapElement(request, "TimeStamp", "string", '2012-08-03 00:00:00')
    response = self.call(action, request)
    return response.findtext("Msg")
```

Now am calling this,

**response = GVService().SignOnReq()**

But here it raises the error:

**File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\elementsoap\HTTPClient.py", line 155, in d
o_request
    raise HTTPError(errcode, errmsg, headers, h.getfile())
elementsoap.HTTPClient.HTTPError: (500, 'Internal Server Error', , )**

I couldn't able to pin-pointing the exact issue in my procedure. Please help on this.

**Please Note**:

In Short, my input parameter are, **TerminalId, StoreCode, TimeStamp**
and expecting response parameters are **Code, Msg, & SessionId** &

I believed, my mistake is in written procedure only, so Please refer this **http://203.215.51.43/GVSignOn/ExecutePortType?WSDL** link as well to pin-point mistakes with input data & expected output data..

& Also am using here GAE sdk 1.6.1v, Python2.5 and imported the elementsoap & elementtree module as well

Let me know, if you need any other info or need to modify the query's info.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code 500 is a server error, not a client error.
You might send unexpected data to the server but it's the server code that crashes.
It might be quite complicated to debug this unless you have access to the server log or get a more detailed error message.

You could log all HTTP requests in ElementSoap and compare the data with
the given documentation. Perhaps the HTTP response body contains more information.